# How to initialize storage for smart contracts in the genesis block

Tags: storage, genesis

I have a simple smart contract that will be added as part of genesis block. Need to initialize the field "message" with default value as constructor is not executed as part of genesis block creation how can we initalize the storage so the property can initalized.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.8.0;

contract HelloWorld {
    string private message = "hello world";

    function getMessage() public view returns (string memory) {
        return message;
    }

    function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

Genesis file

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 1598,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "clique": {
      "period": 15,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "difficulty": "1",
  "gasLimit": "8000000",
  "extradata": "0x0",
  "alloc": {
    "847af7242c2485abe168c2f8793bc9419a197b73": {
      "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {
      "balance": "0x0",
      "code": "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",
      "storage": {
        ???
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What should be the values for storage or how to derive the storage slots for any given smart contract.